# while loop which has two ( !=) operators in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

Linked list. We insert value of a element we want to delete then we find that value and delete it. I have problem with understanding find portion of the code. I dont get how it can be that both condition ever be satisfied (!=)

```
.
.
.
     temp = list;
     previous = list;

while((temp!=NULL) && (temp->value != value))
{
     previous = temp;
     temp=temp->next;
}
```

ok, when we find value that is value we are looking then `temp->value != value` is satisfied BUT then `temp != NULL` isn't satisfied. How can I have both. I really don't get this. They both have to be satisfied but they never will.

Comment: What cannot `temp` be non-null when you're in the middle of the list?

Comment: Before you are allowed to dereference the pointer `temp`, you need to verify that it isn't the `NULL` pointer (`NULL` means you don't have an actual object, non-`NULL` means you have an object). As the operator `&&` does short-circuit evaluation, the second part (`temp->value != value`) is only tested if `temp != NULL`. The logic of this code segment is "while we're not at the end and not yet found the correct node, iterate".

Answer (score 2):

The loop will continue while the condition of the loop is true

```
(temp!=NULL) && (temp->value != value)
```

The loop will stop iterations when the condition will be false or (that is equivalent) when the negation of the condition will be true

```
!( (temp!=NULL) && (temp->value != value) )
```

This (negation of) condition can be rewriten like

```
!(temp!=NULL) || !(temp->value != value)
```

or

```
(temp == NULL) || (temp->value == value)
```

So the loop will stop iterations when either temp is equal to NULL or it is not equal to NULL and temp->value is equal to value.
If temp is equal to NULL then it means that the node that have the data member equal to the value is not found.
If temp is not equal to NULL then it is obvious that the target node to be deleted is found.

Answer (score 0):

There are three possibilities.

When you are not holding the value you are looking for:

```
temp != null // statisfied
temp->value != value // satisfied
```

When you are holding the value you are looking for:

```
temp != null // statisfied
temp->value != value // not satisfied
```

When you are at the end of the list (assuming it ends with null:

```
temp != null // not statisfied
temp->value != value // isn't evaluated (short-circuit using &&)
```

Now you only need to see if you're at the end of the list or at the value you were looking for. Since a lot of times the search-value methods return `NULL` in case of not finding the value - you may just have to return the value you're holding.

Answer (score 0):

You're misinterpreting the `while` loop. Its purpose is to got through all elements of the list (always making `temp` the next element, until the next element is a `NULL` pointer), and stopping when you find the right value.